# Change order of cart columns without overriding template files in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

Is there a solution to change the order of the cart columns without copying the file in my own template folder?

The reason is, that I don't want to overwrite such a crucial template file.

Unfortunately, the order is hardcoded as table in the file `cart.php` and not inside a function.

Is there in this case any "clean" way to change the order of the columns?

Comment: OK thanks. I would accept it as answer if you post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to [override Woocommerce cart/cart.php template via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) as it's hardcoded in the template.

Woocommerce template are made to be overridden so it's not a big deal to do it.

The only annoying thing, is when templates files change in major updates, you will have to make your changes again if the template has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I manage to rearange woocomercerce columns with css grid by setting `grid-template-area` [grid-template-area on smashingmag](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/understanding-css-grid-template-areas/)

here is the css code :

```
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 120px 40px 1fr 80px 100px 20px; /* change value here to fit your theme  */
    grid-template-areas: "product-thumbnail product-quantity product-name product-price product-subtotal product-remove"; /* change columns order here */
}

.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-thumbnail{grid-area: product-thumbnail;}
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-quantity{grid-area:product-quantity;}
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-name{grid-area:product-name;}
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-price{grid-area:product-price;}
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-subtotal{grid-area:product-subtotal;}
.woocommerce-cart-form .shop_table tr .product-remove{grid-area:product-remove;}
```

⚠︎ don't forget to check on mobile !